# Reports to show decimal numbers. CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, expression, crm

I am trying to make a report with expressions. I am currently using the following expression to work out how many hours have been completed. I would like for it to show the decimals for the values. 1.00 would be 1hr, and 0.5 would be 30mins ETC. Is this possible?

My current code is this: `=CDbl(Sum(Fields!incident1_ask_totaldurationValue.Value/60)).ToString("N0", Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper.ReportCultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Parameters))`

If the value is less than 1hr, the result brought back is 0, even if work has been carried out.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have CRM in front of me at the moment but try this

```
=CDbl(Sum(Fields!incident1_ask_totaldurationValue.Value/60.0)).ToString("N1", Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.RdlHelper.ReportCultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Parameters))
```